# Issue with "Meteor mongo" command when connected to separate Mongo Instance

Tags: meteor

When running the "parties" example locally, if I first specify my MONGO_URL to use an already existing mongo instance `meteor mongo` reports that meteor isn't running, even though it is and even though it is connecting just fine to a separate mongo instance.

If you run the meteor app without specifying a separate MONGO_URL, no problems `meteor mongo` works as expected

Now I have also tried setting the MONGO_URL before running `meteor mongo` to no avail. I haven't tried deploying the app to see what would happen.

The one other attempt to troubleshoot is after running the app, I try to connect using meteor mongo with the  `--url localhost:27017` flag it asks for a **Password:**. This is supposed to give me a URL to connect to the database instance, and the request for a Password isn't mongo either, since

a) I don't have authentication enabled on my local instance

b) Even if the local instance isn't running and you run `meteor mongo` it still asks for a password.

In the meteor documentation it notes under meteor mongo:

> For now, you must already have your application running locally with meteor run. This will be easier >in the future.

Is this what they mean?

Obviously, it is isn't crucial that I have shell access from meteor to my local instance since I can always get shell access by just typing mongo, but my concern has to do with deployment, and should I want shell access then, this might be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteor mongo is meant to connect to the mongo database meteor runs when it runs in development, i.e that is run with `meteor run`, without a MONGO_URL or in deployment mode on meteor.com

This means it can't access other mongodbs, for instance if you specify `MONGO_URL`. meteor mongo will actually look for the running process id of the mongodb running in the `.meteor` directory of your project.

The reason `meteor mongo --url localhost:27017` asks for a password is its attempting to connect to meteor.com hosting (if you deployed your app via meteor deploy), so if you deployed your app to test.meteor.com you could access its mongodb uri via `meteor mongo test.meteor.com`. If a password is set it will ask for that password.

To access your local mongodb collection you would have to look at the `/bin` directory of your mongodb instance or use `mongo --dbpath xxx` where xxx is where your database is installed. (Or as you mentioned to use `mongo`)

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly the answer I was looking for.