# Posting data to Meteor's MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, rest, curl, meteor, postman

What would be the best way to post data to Meteor's MongoDB collection ? 
I tried initially using the Postman chrome extension, command-line tool like curl but did not find any luck.

The curl command that I use is :

```
 curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"hacker":"fromcurl","score":100}' http://localhost:3000/players
```

OUTPUT:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
vary: Accept-Encoding
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 17 May 2016 00:37:44 GMT
connection: keep-alive
transfer-encoding: chunked

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

PS : players is the collection/table name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16495135

Comment: @pink612 Does your app need to have a `REST` interface so you can do this from the command line? If not, the generic answer to this is to use meteor methods.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Thanks for your response. I have added the simple:rest package to my meteor app. Still post data to mongo db does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at DDP, Meteor uses this protocol to communicate between client and server. DDP is simple and based on JSON. Meteor’s DDP currently based on WebSockets and SockJS. That's very helpful. I have a case that Websocket cannot work in local LAN network but the connection fall back to SockJS, then everything work fine, that's great!

An example implement DDP communication between Meteor and Python.
Simply create a Meteor method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  clientProcessData: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    // Meteor post data to MongoDB code here
  },
```

Follow the instructions from https://github.com/hharnisc/python-meteor to install python-meteor client and connect to Meteor server.

You can call Meteor method from Python by:

```
client.call('clientProcessData', ["This is a test"], callback_function)
```

Not sure are there any other DDP clients of other programming language, but in my case, python works great!

// Update: There are many of them, but I'm so new here that afraid of posting external link, so please do a simple "DDP client" search on google.